# Can't change language from English

Tags: here-api

Using the Here We Go app version 2.0.12491 (8.30.98.153) I don't have the option to change /download any more languages. Meanwhile in the 2.0.12491 (8.30.97.156) I have the option to choose / download. 
Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the voice guidance you still have the possibility to download different voice packages. Concerning the language of the Here We Go app itself, the language will be automatically detected according of your system settings on your smartphone.